# When to use inner classes in Java for helper classes

Tags: java, inner-classes

If I have for example a class along with a helper class to do some of its functionality, does it make sense to make it as an inner class.

```
    public class Foo {
       private FooHelper helper;

       // constructor & any other logic

       public void doSomeThing() {
         helper.do();
       }
    }

    public class FooHelper {
        public void do() {
         // code
        }
    }
```

In the above case does it make sense to make the `FooHelper` as an inner class ? Apology if this sound stupid but I am little confused about the use cases.

Comment: http://javabeginnerstutorial.com/core-java-tutorial/inner-class/

Comment: Generally for actionlisteners and when you do not want to expose your call to others.

Comment: @Vaibhav Jain thanks for the link, I am aware of the syntax, but m bit confused about when to use it and if there is any trade off

Comment: @SayemAhmed I am not sure if that is the only option available, It seems there could be multiple alternative and being a newbie m not sure about the proper approach, so still digging

Comment: @me_digvijay ...can u elaborate a bit in this regard

Comment: @AnilSharma: Think about this: "Why expose a `thing` to outer world to which the `thing` has nothing to do". 
By this I mean: if you need a functionality (the class and its methods) that is needed for one single class and outer classes don't need it or its functionality, its better not to expose this functionality to other classes. This way you avoid polluting the outer world, which leads to better architecture.

Comment: @me_digvijay - How does this lead to a better architecture ? Looks like it only reduces the number of classes.

Answer (score 95, accepted):

Yes, it makes perfect sense to make it an inner class. If no other classes need it, make it private. If it doesn't require exclusive access to the members of the outer class, make it a static nested class because then it will require less memory space.

Check out the recommendation from [the official tutorial](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/whentouse.html) -

> Use a non-static nested class (or inner class) if you require access
>   to an enclosing instance's non-public fields and methods. Use a static
>   nested class if you don't require this access.

Comment: And when should it be a static inner class ? if there any difference from the functional point of view?

Comment: @Hild: A `static nested class` doesn't have access to the members of the enclosing class (unless it is static). If this matches your requirement, make it static. Non-static inner classes, on the other hand, have full access to the members of the enclosing class.

Comment: @Hild static nested classes do not contain synthetic references to their enclosing class. So unless you have specific reasons to make it non-static always strive to make it a `static nested class`. `Static inner class` is a technically wrong terminology.

Comment: thanks was really useful, but @eddieferetro has a valid point why not uses private method instead

Comment: Why does static nested class require less memory space?

Comment: If we make a helper class into private inner class. Aren't we compromising its testability? Is it worth it?

Comment: Cool piece of advice with `private static class`!

Answer (score 25):

**From JAVA SE Docs**

**Why Use Nested Classes?**

**It is a way of logically grouping classes that are only used in one place:** If a class is useful to only one other class, then it is logical to embed it in that class and keep the two together. Nesting such "helper classes" makes their package more streamlined.

**It increases encapsulation:** Consider two top-level classes, A and B, where B needs access to members of A that would otherwise be declared private. By hiding class B within class A, A's members can be declared private and B can access them. In addition, B itself can be hidden from the outside world.

**It can lead to more readable and maintainable code**: Nesting small classes within top-level classes places the code closer to where it is used.

So Yes, it makes sense to use *FooHelper* as an inner class.

Answer (score 22):

If you think that `FooHelper` will **not at all be useful** for other classes than `Foo`, then it makes sense to make it as `private` *inner class* of `Foo`. One example of this kind of design can be found in `HashMap` where it defines a private inner class `KeySet`

Otherwise having it as a `private` instance looks good.

Answer (score 9):

Here are some uses of inner classes.

- Inner classes are used to get functionality which can get an object better than method.
- They can be used in the case when a set of multiple operations are required and chances of reusability are good inside the class and they will not be accessed but methods outside the outer class.
- Inner classes are made to achieve multiple inheritance also.
- Inner classes are used when they are useful in class context.
- They are used to separate logic inside classes.

So if you have some requirement matching above points than inner classes can be used. It is always better to make inner class `private` to prevent access from other classes. In your case use of inner classes is helpful to make code readable and separate logic in the outer class.

Answer (score 3):

**As per Oracle Docs, Simply Explained**

Compelling reasons for using nested classes include the following:

**It is a way of logically grouping classes that are only used in one place:** If a class is useful to only one other class, then it is logical to embed it in that class and keep the two together. Nesting such "helper classes" makes their package more streamlined.

**It increases encapsulation:** Consider two top-level classes, A and B, where B needs access to members of A that would otherwise be declared private. By hiding class B within class A, A's members can be declared private and B can access them. In addition, B itself can be hidden from the outside world.

**It can lead to more readable and maintainable code:** Nesting small classes within top-level classes places the code closer to where it is used.

Answer (score 2):

Inner classes make sense when they are tiny and don't need names. Listeners in GUIs are classic examples where they make sense.

If the class is big and important, it should be named and placed in a separate file.

The listener classes in normal GUI examples do one tiny thing, usually just dispatch to some other function to do real work.

I also often use static nested classes (which are technically not inner classes) for classes which are only used in the context of another class - [Map.Entry](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/Map.Entry.html) is a good example of this. It's only used in conjunction with a Map, so having the definition of Entry be a part of the Map interface makes organizational sense.

I don't generally have much use for other types of nested classes, like nonstatic member classes and local classes. But they do occasionally come in useful. For a good example of a legitimate use for member classes, see the source code for LinkedList.ListItr. This is a private inner class whose purpose is to provide an implementation of [ListIterator](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/ListIterator.html) for a [LinkedList](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/LinkedList.html). To do this, it's useful to have access to the private data inside the LinkedList. To achieve this using only top-level classes, it would have been necessary to expose more public methods in LinkedList to allow the ListIterator to get at the underlying implementation of the LinkedList. Instead, using an inner class allows LinkedList to keep its implementation private, as it should be.

Comment: Sorry, im an eternal newbie and would like an explanation because I cannot see the place of innerclases in the OOP world:

They can access to **private** members of outer class... 

You can't reuse them, only by copy-pasting...

Make the code ugly and more hard to read and mantain... (continues)

Comment: I only understand your argument of not to expose a lot of public methods when optimizing an app, but cannot see what is it sense in GUIs: Listener pattern gives you the option of change an item behavior (what to do in an button 'onclick' event, for example) in execution time. If the listener is an inner class it usually indicates that you, really, didn't need listener capabilities: you wanted an 'onClick' method that you will never reuse (like occurs usually in android)

Comment: @eddieferetro one use cases I can think of is not exposing an entire object when it is to be used in a specific class.

Comment: @hild but, if its an especific object for an specific class why not create private methods in outer class withouth create a new innerclass?.

Comment: @eddieferetro The inner class is just a way to cleanly separate some functionality that really belongs to the original outer class. Some piece of functionality in your outer class would be most clear if it was implemented in a separate class.Even though it's in a separate class, the functionality is very closely tied to way that the outer class works.

Comment: @arun in a innerclass you can use variables that are: private members of outer class, private vars of the method that creates the inner class, class's members, method variables... that is not a readability improvement... I only see it more clean when your are using a pattern that you don't really need (normally because is imposed by an API that you are using, like listeners on android) and you want to avoid creating structures that you will not reuse. I see them like a pattern-destroyer-pattern.

Comment: @eddieferetro see here http://www.javaworld.com/javaqa/2000-03/02-qa-innerclass.html

Answer (score 1):

Yes, the advantage of using inner class is it can access members of outer class.In your case , if you think your `FooHelper` is not to be used by any other class,you can make it a inner class.

To check out the utility of inner class, go through the examples of AWT. Anonymous inner classes are widely used in event handlers.

Answer (score 0):

What is `Foo`'s scope? When `Foo` is [domain model class](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Domain-driven_design) with it's own lifecycle and `helper` is common service, seems like mixing of two objects with very different scope/lifecycle.

Typically domain entity has it's own lifecycle from creation, persistence to it's GC. On the other hand, helper or service is either static or better *dynamic* with lifecycle equals to the whole app, e.g. spring bean.

Once your domain entity would contain reference of a service it can bring you serious problems. E.g. every call to repository's `Get` needs to inject reference of this service into domain entity. I'd recommend to avoid this pattern.

It's not apparent for me who will make instance of `Helper` for you.

Answer (score 0):

Hild, Yes, it makes sense to use an inner class in many cases.

Think of it this way - the inner class will live and die with the outer class, so any functionality that is specifically needed for the outer class can be added to the inner class. 
Popular examples are - Listeners in most cases - Types of KeyListeners, MouseListeners, eventListeners.

Classes in Java allow you to have specific functionality, but sometimes you may need to have a separate specialized functionality but it also needs to be intimately tied to the class you're designing.

There can be four types of inner classes. A simple google search can help you to find out more about them.

Answer (score 0):

Nested Classes,enable you to logically group classes that are only used in one place, increase the use of encapsulation, and create more readable and maintainable code. Local classes, anonymous classes.

http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/whentouse.html