# Difference between nested static and non static class

Tags: java

I'm trying to visualize real time or hypothetical example (Human body, bus etc any existence in nature)  to differentiate between static and non static nested classes. Its little strange question, but I think its good relate with real world :)

Usually I follow below concept

```
class A
{
    class B
    {
        // static int x; not allowed here
    }

    static class C
    {
        static int x; // allowed here
    }
}

class Test
{
    public static void main(String… str)
    {
        A a = new A();

        // Non-Static Inner Class
        // Requires enclosing instance
        A.B obj1 = a.new B(); 

        // Static Inner Class
        // No need for reference of object to the outer class
        A.C obj2 = new A.C(); 
    }
}
```

But its something just code and formula to code. But am curious to know how people understand with any hypothetical scenario if any.

Please share..!

Comment: @ Hovercraft Full Of Eels, I know answer is given, but am looking some real world example. Please understand

Comment: Keep looking. You have the whole internet at your fingertips.

Comment: @hqt, Have seen all these..! But these are explaining only coding perspective. Looking for real world example ..to example someone very lame

Comment: Please take a look at this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18396016/when-to-use-inner-classes-in-java-for-helper-classes

Comment: @JonLe Imagine that a nested class cannot  be instantiated without instantiating the parent class. So, you cannot have a head without a person. The exception is a static nested class. A static nested class can be instantiated without instantiating the parent. See also the links provided by the others.

Comment: @MenelaosBakopoulos By "parent" you probably meant "outer" class. Anyway nice example with Body and Head analogy.